# AWS Data Pipeline RedshiftCopy activity No suitable drivers

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying a redshift copyactivity from S3 to Redshift, and getting the below error when I run it.

```
01 Feb 2017 04:08:38,467 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller: Executing: amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.RedshiftCopyActivity@63859f83
01 Feb 2017 04:08:38,962 [ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev No suitable driver found for postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev
01 Feb 2017 04:08:39,063 [ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev No suitable driver found for postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev
01 Feb 2017 04:08:39,265 [ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev No suitable driver found for postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev
01 Feb 2017 04:08:39,666 [ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev No suitable driver found for postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev
01 Feb 2017 04:08:40,468 [ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev No suitable driver found for postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev
01 Feb 2017 04:08:40,473 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.HeartBeatService: Finished waiting for heartbeat thread @RedshiftLoadActivity_2017-02-01T03:43:47_Attempt=3
01 Feb 2017 04:08:40,473 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE_@Ec2Instance_2017-02-01T03:43:47-0) df-0657690RH3EEUVGYXWE amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller: Work RedshiftCopyActivity took 0:2 to complete
```

I am able to see someone suggesting to use postgresql drivers, instead of redshift drivers.

But when I try with postgresql drivers, I get the error as :

```
No suitable driver found for postgresql://.....
```

Please suggest where should I make the corrections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact **No suitable driver found for postgresql:/redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev** are you sure that this is the right URL the URL should look like this :

```
jdbc:postgresql://redshiftHost:5439/trivusdev?OpenSourceSubProtocolOverride=true
```

I think you miss a `jdbc:..` and `/` before the host.

You can learn more here : [Creating a custom Database connection](http://help.boomi.com/atomsphere/GUID-936D6F4C-09F7-40D9-9AE5-E5F709DEE09B.html)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thats what was missing, its creating the coneection OK now.